# Wrong days Javascript countdown

Tags: javascript, date, math

My Javascript counter shows wrong numbers of days. With the code below the counter shows 30 days but this is not right (at the moment this has to be 0 days).

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var enddate = new Date( "2021","04","23" ).getTime();
        var countdown = setInterval(function() {
            var datetime_now = new Date() . getTime();
            var time_left = enddate - datetime_now;
            var days = Math.floor(time_left / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((time_left % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((time_left % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((time_left % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Who can help me??

Comment: Month numbers in JavaScript start at 0, not 1. So your date is May 23, not April 23.

Comment: My suggestion is, it's always a good idea to just "alert()" each value that you're setting, and then you can interrogate where the calc is (supposedly) going wrong.  This would have alerted you (no pun intended) to the fact that the value for "enddate" was greater than "datetime_now" - which is not what you'd expect, given the date that you believed you were setting for "enddate".  So after the "time_left" value was set, all of the other calculations after that were correct - but likewise, just not based on the original values that you would have been expecting to have been set.